# How to force reference in one xml document

Tags: xml

Can you tell me how to force reference (via `xsd` file) in `xml` document ?

Lets consider:

```
<city>
 <owners>
  <owner id="123">
    <name>John></name>
    ...
  </owner>
 </ownwers>
 <dogs>
  <dog>
    <idOwner>123</idOwner> <!-- that's ok because in this file there exists owner with id 123 -->
    ...
  </dog>
  <dog>
    <idOwner>1234</idOwner> <!-- that's not ok because in this file it doesn't exist owner with id 1234, so validation error should happen -->
    ...
  </dog>
 </dogs>
</city>
```

Can you help me reach such behaviour ? I mean validation of proper reference from dog to its owner (so owner id must exists in this `xml` file).

Comment: I don't understand you. I would like to create schema (xsd file) which force such behaviour. Above xml is only example.

Comment: References are usually handled by ID and IDREF type attributes. Is it possible to make your `idOwner` element an attribute of `dog`? You'd also have to change the ID's a little; ID type attributes can't start with a number.

Comment: @DanielHaley yes I can change everything. Can you be more precisely ? In particular I don't understand: *ID type attributes can't start with a number.*

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make `idOwner` an attribute of `dog`.

Have the attribute type for `id` be [`xs:ID`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#ID).

Have the attribute type for `idOwner` be [`xs:IDREF`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#IDREF).

[See here for more information on the attribute type validity constraints.](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types)

Example...

**XSD**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="city">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="owners"/>
        <xs:element ref="dogs"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="owners">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="owner"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="owner">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="dogs">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="dog"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="dog">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="idOwner" use="required" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**

```
<city xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="so.xsd">
    <owners>
        <owner id="ID-123">
            <name>John></name>
        </owner>
    </owners>
    <dogs>
        <dog idOwner="ID-123"/>
        <dog idOwner="ID-1234"/><!-- INVALID idOwner -->
    </dogs>
</city>
```